# Button status doesn't change in a loop

Tags: ios, loops, button, while-loop

In my small app, user clicks on "ON" button then I call a method with a while loop and "OFF" button should appear, however my "OFF" button does not show up.

```
-(void) myMethod{

    while (_onButton.selected) {

        [self vibrate];
         NSLog(@"working");
    } 
}


- (IBAction)on:(id)sender {

    _offButton.hidden=NO;
    _offButton.selected=NO;
    _onButton.hidden=YES;
    _onButton.selected=YES;

       [self myMethod];


}

- (IBAction)off:(id)sender {

    _onButton.hidden=NO;
    _offButton.hidden=YES;
    _onButton.selected=NO;
    _offButton.selected=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using this loop:

```
while (_onButton.selected) {

    [self vibrate];
     NSLog(@"working");
}
```

You aren't allowing the runloop to process new events, and so the button will never have the opportunity to change state (as it won't receive touches from the user).  This is very bad and you shouldn't do this.

Instead continue your vibration by using a sound delegate method that continues all the time the button is selected (you don't show how you perform your vibration, so I cannot give more detail here).

**EDIT** After comment from OP:

```
- (void)vibrate
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

OK, AudioServices provides a "completion procedure" via `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion()` which will allow you to replay the vibration "sound" all the time the button is selected.  Use this mechanism rather than the `while` loop.

Comment: - (void) vibrate {
    
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
} This is my vibrate method

Comment: Actually I want to wait between infinite loops since I want it to vibrate with intervals user decides. I have a slider for that and I want to call vibrate method with that intervals

Comment: @ArdaKeskiner Then you need to set-up a timer in the *Sound completion procedure* and play the vibration sounds in the *timer fired method* instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop mate. change the while loop like this:

```
while (_onButton.selected) {

[self vibrate];
 NSLog(@"working");
_onButton.selected = NO;
}
```

or 
    while (_onButton.selected) {

```
[self vibrate];
 NSLog(@"working");
break;
}
```

Comment: However, I want this loop to continue until I stop with the "OFF" button

Comment: Well you cannot use an infiniteloop in the UIThread, cause it's gonna block the UI. Try to run this method in another thread using `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:object];`